# Help with showing a limit of the supremum of a function exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This question was given in a past exam at my university.

Let $f:\lbrack 0,2\rbrack\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. For all $\delta\in(0,1\rbrack$ define $g(\delta):=\text{sup}\lbrace|f(x)-f(1)|:x\in\lbrack 1-\delta,1+\delta\rbrack\rbrace.$ Show that the limit
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0}g(\delta)$$ exists.

I know that $g$ is an increasing function, and I see that intuitively this should be true and $g(\delta)\to 0$ as $\delta\to 0$ but I need some help proving this.

Edit: What I have done so far is note that $x\in\lbrack 1-\delta,1+\delta\rbrack$ if $|x-1|\leq\delta$ so if $\delta\to 0$ we should have $x\to 1,$ but I am not sure how to do this formally. Maybe, $\delta\to 0$ if given any $\gamma>0,$ $\delta<\gamma,$ so $|x-1|<\gamma,$ so we should have $x\to 1.$ But since I don't know if $f$ is continuous or not I am not sure how to use this.

Comment: This is almost obvious! As you mention that $g(\delta)$ is increasing, it follows that if $\delta \to 0^{+}$ and $\delta$ decreases towards $0$, $g(\delta)$ is also decreasing and since is bounded below by $0$, the limit $\lim_{\delta \to 0^{+}}g(\delta)$ exists.

Comment: g should be a decreasing function?

Comment: ah, never mind. I see.

Comment: Sorry, I've been studying non-stop for about 2 days, I think my brain is starting to die. I just couldn't think of how to write it out formally.

Comment: @user137769: when $\delta$ decreases to go towards $0$ then $g(\delta)$ will also decrease. An increasing function increases with its argument and at the same it also decreases when its argument decreases. Basically the direction of growth is same as that of the argument.